# Uploading a file on Angular 5 and send it to Java Spring Back End

Tags: java, spring, angular

I have a problem on my app. I upload a file on Angular 5 but I can't give to my Java Spring Back end in order to insert it to a database.

I receive a 500 error when I try to send the `frmData` to Java Controller.

Does any one has a solution? Here is my code :

my component .html :

```
<ng-container>
  <input type="file" id="uploadFile" multiple 
         (change)="getFileDetails($event.target.file)">
</ng-container></div>
```

my component .ts :

```
getFileDetails (e) {
  //console.log (e.target.files);
  for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
    this.myFiles.push(e.target.files[i]);
  }
}

addFollowUp1() {            
  const frmData = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0; i < this.myFiles.length; i++) {
    frmData.append("file", this.myFiles[i]);
  }

  this.followUpService.addFollowUpAttachment(frmData).subscribe();
}
```

And my Service.ts :

```
public addFollowUpAttachment(file: FormData): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('/SV-AUD/api/attachment/addAttachment', file );
}
```

On java Back-end here is the controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/attachment")
public class AttachmentController {

  @Autowired
  private AttachmentService attachmentService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/addAttachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void addFollowUpAttachment(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile files) throws ApcException {    
    System.out.println("test");
    attachmentService.addFollowUpAttachment(files);    
  }    
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Can you check the logs from the java backend and see what the error is?

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't give me any error coming from the java backend

Comment: Is the `System.out.println("test");` in the logs?

Comment: no it is not , so I think that when angular tries to reach the controller it doesn't find one that corresponds to the parameter that I give him

Comment: Write a @GetMapping method in that controller which returns "Hello World!". Call that from a browser. Capture the URL of the request that Angular sends in that POST request. Compare the two. You're very likely hitting wrong URL from Angular.

Comment: Can you try and use an absolute URL (i.e. the full URL) to point to the java backend rather than a relative one?

Comment: I've found the problem , instead of $event.target.file I user only $event , now I finally get an error from the java backend xD

Comment: I still need you help xD Now my backends has the file , when I convert the file in bytes in works , however I can't insert it into oracle database It gives me an error, I tried convert it in bytes but still same problem

Comment: the problem is that the type of the file that I'm trying to insert isn't the same of the column , the column type is BLOB

Comment: Don't add to this question in comments. If you have solved it yourself then either write up the solution to the question you have asked as your own answer or just delete the question. Then ask a new question with the Oracle issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem , instead of $event.target.file I used only $event , now I finally get an error from the java backend xD

```
<ng-container>
  <input type="file" id="uploadFile" multiple (change)="getFileDetails($event)">
</ng-container></div>
```